# How do I check out an SVN project into Eclipse as a Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ant, subversive

I was trying to check out a project from SVN using Eclipse. I tried using "Checkout As" to make it into a "Java project from existing Ant script", but the project wizard requires the file to have already been downloaded. Is there a way to checkout the project into Eclipse as a Java project, without having to download it elsewhere first?

(I am using Eclipse Ganymade 3.4.1 with Subversive.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If it wasn't checked in as a Java Project, you can add the java nature as shown [here](http://enarion.net/programming/tools/eclipse/changing-general-project-to-java-project/).

Answer (score 42):

Here are the steps:

- Install the subclipse plugin (provides svn connectivity in eclipse) and connect to the repository. Instructions here:
  http://subclipse.tigris.org/install.html
- Go to File->New->Other->Under the SVN category, select Checkout Projects from SVN.
- Select your project's root folder and select checkout as a project in the workspace.

It seems you are checking the .project file into the source repository. I would suggest not checking in the .project file so users can have their own version of the file. Also, if you use the subclipse plugin it allows you to check out and configure a source folder as a java project. This process creates the correct .project for you(with the java nature),

Comment: This doesn't make it a Java project if it's not already configured as so in the repository.

Comment: I would recommend checking out the project using the File system. Then in Eclipse, import existing Java project. It shouldn't matter what is in the repository, Eclipse should make it a Java project. Or as close to one as possible.

Comment: @Tony What is a "File System"

Comment: @user2763361 Sorry for the late response. But, simply using an external client like Tortoise or the cmd line of your operating system.

Answer (score 5):

http://ajmoore.blogspot.com/2007/11/svn-java-project-with-eclipse.html

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the .classpath too, form a java project.
I made a dummy java project and looked in the workspace for this dummy java project to see what is required.
I transferred the two files. profile and .claspath to my checked out, and disconnected  source from my subversion server.
From then on it turned to a java project from just a plain old project.

Answer (score 0):

If the were checked as plugin-projects, than you just need to check them out. But do not select the "trunk"(for example) to speed it up. You must select all the projects you want to check out and proceed. Eclipse will than recognize them as such.