# How to Open an Existing SVN Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I just started a new project which has previously been developed in Eclipse. I have not used Eclipse since 2006 and it was for a short non-SVN-controlled project at that time. I have extensive experience with NetBeans and Visual Studio.

The code base is in an SVN repository. I have installed Eclipse (Helios) and TortiseSVN and downloaded the source. I see that there is a .project file and that it contains some eclipse references.

I would like to import the project so that I can edit the files under SVN control. I would then like to either commit the files via the Tortoise client, or more ideally, directly in Eclipse.

I have already reviewed a couple of web sites and questions on this forum, but have not been able to find a how to for this particular use case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- You'll first need to install an SVN plugin for Eclipse - check out [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).
- [The answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408110/how-do-i-check-out-an-svn-project-into-eclipse-as-a-java-project) document the steps for checking out from an SVN repository.

Note

- You'll find the commands for SVN under the `Team` sub-menu when you right click on your project.
- I've had trouble in the past when connecting to SVN repositories using the `svn+ssh://` protocol - a quick fix is to change the `SVN interface` (under `Window > Preferences > Team > SVN`) to the pure Java option (SVNKit IIRC).

Comment: I'd recommend Subclipe. Subversive has *never* worked properly for me, and I'm a seasoned software developer.

Comment: @Chris Horses for courses.  I have had nothing but good experiences with Subversive.

Answer (score 7):

**Eclipse Mars (4.5.1)**

1. Install an **SVN plugin** from Help > Eclipse Marketplace... > type "Subversive" or "Subclipse" > press Enter > click on Install

   [image: Help Eclipse Marketplace]
   [image: Eclipse Marketplace]
2. Go to **File > New > Project...** > type "SVN" > select "Checkout Projects from SVN" or "Project from SVN" (it depends on the installed plugin(s)) > select repository > Next > select project > Finish

   [image: File New Project]

   [image: Checkout Projects from SVN]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the svn plugin installed see here - 
http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php

- From Eclipse's File menu, choose Import to display the import manager.
- Choose Checkout Projects from SVN
- Create a new location
- Enter your repository url
- Hit finish

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directrly from Eclipse if you install [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) or [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) plugin. Then you can either reimpoort your project into workspace or use Team -> Share option in context menu (right-click) of the project.