# Can anyone tell me how to download the project

Tags: android

I found an interesting project

http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/

with the level of my knowledge I can not understand on the move, I wanted to download and  run eclipse but can not download it.

can someone know where I can download

Comment: You'd need SVN and then do what it says **[here](http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/source/checkout)** to *clone* the repository.

Comment: I think [this][1] can help you to open SVN project into your workspace.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408110/how-do-i-check-out-an-svn-project-into-eclipse-as-a-java-project

Comment: That's actually not true .. you can also download it here: http://android-protips-location.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ However, using SVN is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a SVN repository. SVN is a version control system (Software used to track changes to your code etc) . You have to check out the repository using an SVN client of some sort.

check this tutorial out for using an SVN client.
http://www.themememe.com/subversion-for-absolute-beginners

Since you dont want to contribute any changes back to the project, you can use simply look up the importing part. But I recommend you learn more about SVN and other version control systems such as GIT. They will really help you in any kind of software engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Download the SVN tortise softaware than paste the project link as it is like :

svn checkout http://android-protips-location.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/