# Can I check out an SVN project to a dynamic web project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am looking for a way to check out a java project from SVN, preferably using subclipse, and sync it with a dynamic web project in my workspace in eclipse.

I would ideally like the Checkout function to download the contents of the java project in the repository into a WebContent folder in my dynamic web project. Is it possible to do this by editing a file path somewhere or by any other means?

I have looked and found similar question answered already (such as
[How do I check out an SVN project into Eclipse as a Java project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408110/how-do-i-check-out-an-svn-project-into-eclipse-as-a-java-project)) but I'm not sure they can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/). I use this plugin to checkout projects from SVN.

The Subversive project is aimed to integrate the Subversion (SVN) version control system with the Eclipse platform. Using the Subversive plug-in, you can work with projects stored in Subversion repositories directly from the Eclipse workbench in a way similar to work with other Eclipse version control providers, such as CVS and Git.